# How to simulate the "genie" effect with flex4 effects?

Tags: apache-flex, effects

Does someone know how can I simulate the genie effect (like in Mac OS X)
in flex4 using the new spark effects?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Ginny Effect Modoki](http://wonderfl.net/c/qnTR/).. seems like what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Also try this, using PixelBender: http://blog.platogo.com/2009/05/genie-in-a-bottle/